# %copy to macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I would like to store the content of a macro source code into a variable in order to do some regex on it later.

Say I have the following macro function:

```
%MACRO sleep
/*--------------------------------------
pauses for the desired amount of seconds
---------------------------------------*/ 
(sec
) / STORE SOURCE DES='pauses for the desired amount of seconds';
/* EXAMPLE:
%sleep(3);
*/
DATA _NULL_;
vVar1=SLEEP(%eval(&sec*1000));
RUN;
%mend;
```

I can display the code in the log using:

```
%copy sleep /source;
```

However I would like to be able to write:

```
%let sleep_source = %get_source(sleep);
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to extract the examples (or tests) and do things like :

```
%run_examples(sleep)
%run_tests(sleep)    # if I define tests in the function's body
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `OUTFILE=` option of the `%COPY` macro.  My testing shows OUTFILE does not like to be a SOURCE catalog entry, so this example uses an external file in the WORK libref folder.  Note: %COPY overwrites an existing OUTFILE.

```
libname mymacros 'c:\temp';
option mstored sasmstore=mymacros;

%MACRO sleep
/*--------------------------------------
pauses for the desired amount of seconds
---------------------------------------*/ 
(
  sec /* number of seconds to sleep */
) 
/ STORE SOURCE DES='pauses for the desired amount of seconds';
/* EXAMPLE:
%sleep(3);
*/
DATA _NULL_;
vVar1=SLEEP(%eval(&sec*1000));
RUN;
%mend;

filename extract "%sysfunc(pathname(work))\source-code.sas";

%copy sleep / outfile=extract source;

data _null_;
  infile extract;
  input;
  put _infile_;

  * do regex tests on the macros source code lines ;
  * ... ;
run;
```

%SLEEP: you might not always want the macro to create code with a step boundary.  You could 
`%sysfunc(sleep(%eval(&sec)*1000))` instead.

Comment: Thank you, i'll test this ASAP

Comment: FIY I reworked your answer into a macro function that creates a macro variable. Not as clean as I wished though, and I can't reach the syntax I would prefer.

Comment: The created `source-code.sas` file will be deleted when the SAS session is closed right ?

Comment: Yes, files in the folder of WORK get deleted at session termination.  There might be some cases of a resource locked file being left behind, like *maybe* an unclosed ODS destination. You could also try using using a TEMP fileref once the read back is known to work.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use autocall macros instead?  Then you could make a fileref that points to the same path that you are using for your autocall macros.  So it is easy to read the source code from the actual text file that contains it.

```
filename mymacros '/path';
options sasautos=(mymacros);

data _null_;
  infile mymacros('sleep.sas');
  ...
run;
```

Comment: To be honest it's been a headache to decide between both systems and I don't fully understand their benefits and flaws yet but I decided to invest time in testing compiled stored macros first, it seemed cleaner and easier at first sight. I liked the idea of macros belonging to a library and I think I could setup a development environment in a library and easily "commit" functions to the stable working environment, using the answer to this question.

Comment: A `%commit` macro would basically change the `sasmstore` option, execute the macro definition, and change `sasmstore` back to the development library. It might be possible with autocall too.

Comment: To manage an autocall library use your native version control. We have used RCS on Unix for years.  If even have `%co()` and `%ci()` SAS macros for working with RCS on Unix.

Answer (score 0):

I reworked Richard's answer to wrap it into a macro and get a macro variable out of it.

I'm not completely happy as it creates global variable `src_code` and several `_temp_outi` and I can't use it with the syntax I wanted, but it does the job.

```
%macro get_source(mac, line_sep = \n);
%global src_code;
filename extract "%sysfunc(pathname(work))\temp-source-code.sas";
%copy &mac / outfile=extract source;

data _null_;
  infile extract;
  input;
  call symput('_temp_out'||strip(_n_), _infile_);
  call symput('last_n', _n_);
run;

%let src_code = %superq(_temp_out1);
%do i = 2 %to &last_n;
  %let curr_var = _temp_out&i;
  %let src_code = &src_code&line_sep.%superq(&curr_var);
%end;
%mend;
```

Let's test it:

```
%get_source(sleep) /* creates a src_code global variable containing the source code */   
%put %superq(src_code);
```

will print to the log:

> ```
> %MACRO sleep\n/*--------------------------------------\npauses for the desired amount of 
> seconds\n---------------------------------------*/ \n(sec\n) / STORE SOURCE;\n/* EXAMPLE:\n%sleep(3);\n*/\nDATA 
> _NULL_;\nvVar1=SLEEP(%eval(&sec*1000));\nRUN;\n%mend;
> ```